# Deletion is slow in oracle DB

Tags: oracle, plsql, query-optimization

We have a table that doesn't have much data. The table has 3 partitions and we are deleting data in one partition only.
delete from table AB partition(A) where id=value;
here id has an index also but still delete is slow.
The datatype of id is varchar2 and the value is number.

Please help me to understand why the delete statement is slow.

Comment: casting `value` to a string would remove the need for implicit conversion. Is there a trigger on the table being called during a DELETE? Are there any child tables tied to the record you are deleting with a foreign key? if there is a FK, are the columns in the child tables indexed?

Comment: i suggest including an execution plan or even an autotrace/sql monitoring report - otherwise, you're asking us to guess why your DELETE is slow

Comment: How many rows are there in the table, how many will be deleted with the where clause and what is the delete statement that you are using , is it just DELTE from table where col1 = 'some value' or it is joining with other tables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the index has much use in this case. It has to evaluate every single row in the partition to see if it matches id=value. Typically this will be a full table scan and no index will be used. It totally depends on the number of rows in the partition how long it will take. But maybe i did not understand the question properly. I presumed "value" is a column in the same table, like ID.

Comment: If the index does not help, due to the FTS, then it actually hinders, because the index segment itself has to be maintained, along with the table.  And all other indexes on the table will also have to be updated.  Due to the necessary updateing of indexes, a DELETE (as well as UPDATE and INSERT) can be rather expensive operations.  That's exactly why creating an index is a tradeoff between better SELECT and worse performing DML.